# Eclipse autocomplete broken between certain lines of code

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

I've been having issues with Eclipse's autocomplete for a while, as it stops working halfway through coding a project. After lots of unsuccessful debugging, I tried narrowing down my code and have the resulting bare-bones example of my file (minus lots of other functions):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> zlist = new ArrayList();
        zlist.forEach(fileName -> { // CONTENT-ASSIST BREAKS HERE
            String test = "";
            if (true) { // CONTENT-ASSIST WORKS RIGHT AFTER THIS LINE

            }
        });

        Iterator<String> iter = null;

        while ("".equals("")){}
    }
}
```

For some reason, none of the content-assist (`Ctrl+Space`) works between the forEach and the if statement. Commenting out either *Iterator* or *while loop* line makes it work again, but I need that current setup. The file runs fine without errors too. Is there a reason why this occurs, and is there a proper fix?

- I have checked: `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` and `Java Proposals` is checked.
- Booting up Eclipse in *-clean* mode didn't help, nor did cleaning or rebuilding the project.
- The issue occurs even in a new workspace and when I create a new file with the same code (it being the only file in the project).

My setup is: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Neon.1 Release (4.6.1). Windows 7 64-bit.

Here's some screenshots of the errors:

[image: Working content-assist before the for declaration][image: Broken content-assist between the for and the if statement][image: Works again after the if statement][image: Commenting out the Iterator line makes it work]

The last screenshot shows it working when I comment out the Iterator declaration at the bottom. Not quite sure why that affects the autocomplete.

Comment: Nice question; but I guess is more the "product bug" like category. Meaning: if you dont get good answers here (which I almost assume will happen); you better try some eclipse forums / bug trackers.

Comment: I had a similar problem once (inside a lambda as well). It _seemed_ like one of the plugins that was installed, and was contributing to the content assist menu, was crashing, so the content didn't show.

Comment: Have you tried this on the **Neon.2** Release?

Comment: Yeah, it also doesn't work in Neon.2. I also tried in Mars.2 and it also doesn't work.